# PhalconPHP $di security concern with print_r on Resultset objects displays PDO password

Tags: security, phalcon

Let's say I want to display all the records a particular SELECT statement returned. So I do something as simple as this:

```
<?php
$listings=ProductListings::find(array());//ProductListings is my model
foreach($listings as $listing)
{
  echo '<pre>'.print_r($listing,true).'</pre>';
}
?>
```

But, instead of seeing a clean-looking output, like one unsavvy with Phalcon would expect, I see a massive screen splashing properties via `di:protected` including my config and the disturbing:

```
[db] => Phalcon\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql Object
    (
        [_eventsManager:protected] => 
        [_descriptor:protected] => Array
           (
               [host] => localhost
               [username] => **myUsername**
               [password] => **myPassword**
               [dbname] => **myDatabaseName**
               [charset] => utf8
           )
```

I know somewhere down the line, I'm gonna find myself doing a `print_r` and the database information is gonna go public; or worse, a search engine will cache the page with my sensitive data in tact. Whether someone can make use of such information or not, that's not the point. I don't want such information displayed in the first place when I do a `print_r`. Security concerns aside, I don't wanna have to search pages and pages worth of clutter to find the data I'm interested in.

My question to you is, coming from a design point of view, what options do we have as Phalcon developers to add another layer of security to our applications, so these protected properties are less likely to expose our sensitive data with one wrong slip of a `print_r` when we're debugging? The same problem is evident with all Phalcon-related objects which store references to the di. I imagine I could do something with output buffering to scan the output every time for possible slips, but that would just be silly. Being considerate of Phalcon's architecture, what kind of countermeasures can we take in an effort to keep our applications secure?

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer:** There is no way to get around this, I'm afraid.

**Somewhat longer (but probably equally unsatisfying) answer:**

Bear these two facts in mind:

- `print_r` is, as you rightly said, a means of debugging. It will print out all the contents of a variable, regardless of how sensitive the information contained might be to you.
- The concept of dependency injection does not work without a DI container. This container is designed to hold all relevant parts of your application like the database interface, the view engine etc., therefore making it the sacred core of your entire app.

Understand that what you're doing is exposing the inner sanctum of your app by using `print_r($di)` or on any component therein (because they also hold a reference to the DI). It's probably the worst thing you can do, because - as you correctly pointed out - if you forget to remove one of these debugging calls, it would be a worst case scenario in terms of security.

**Conclusion:**
You have to use another way of doing safer debug outputs. Never output your DI container in its entirety, never output more data than you really need for debugging.

I would recommend limiting that output to stuff like the current route, active controller and action, variables present in your view and possibly other less sensitive data.

If you would like to safely debug your SQL statements, I would recommend reading [this part of the Phalcon documentation](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/models.html#logging-low-level-sql-statements).

Comment: Not a very satisfying answer, I'm looking for something creative, like altering the functionality of print_r by unregistering it as a function then redefining it as your own custom implementation or maybe some sort of magic method solution which gets called during a print_r which you can hack onto the phalcon classes somehow. I know PHP has a lot of little-known extensions for doing stuff like this.

Comment: If you're willing to put the security of your application at stake by relying on such an extension, well, it's up to you, of course. I would still strongly advise against doing this instead of just using a safer method of outputting debug information.

Comment: What about the `__debugInfo` magic method and either creating a wrapper for each class in Phalcon, or directly editing the zephir source code and re-compiling a private build including such a method on every class? Or requesting such a feature from the team, but I'm not sure where to post such a feature request.

Comment: You can always define a constant `ENV` of `dev` or `prod` depending on the url (your local machine or production host) and make your own `print_r` function to do nothing if in production mode.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
<?php
$listings=ProductListings::find(array());

foreach($listings as $listing)
{
  echo '<pre>'.print_r($listing->toArray(), true).'</pre>';
}
?>
```